# Android, some complement in my xml can't show

Tags: android, intellij-idea

[It worked at background. so strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFXDj.png)I try ctrl + left click, but can't inside:

Here is the textcolor:
[image]

but in background it will work

I have tried to invalidata and restart , not work
delete idea and .iml,  not work
cancel check power save mode ,not work
I think it may caused bt my code. so strange

help please

My English is poor. haha.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_head_img"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/photo" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/drawer_main"
            style="@style/drawer_item"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawer_item_icon1"
            android:text="首页" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/drawer_msg"
            style="@style/drawer_item"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawer_item_icon"
            android:text="消息" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/drawer_contact"
            style="@style/drawer_item"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawer_item_icon2"
            android:text="联系人" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/drawer_system"
            style="@style/drawer_item"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawer_item_icon6"
            android:text="教务系统" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/drawer_tools"
            style="@style/drawer_item"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawer_item_icon3"
            android:text="更多功能" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/drawer_about"
            style="@style/drawer_item"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawer_item_icon4"
            android:text="关于" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/drawer_exit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_exit"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:text="退出登录"

        android:textColor="@color/selector_leftmenu_exit" />

</LinearLayout>





 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/black_txt"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Delete namespace declaration for android from parent layout and re-import again! Is it also your textColor attribute is already attached to the view?

Comment: I tried to delete namespace declaration. It doesn't work.  What't the meaning of attached to the view.   Thank you

Comment: Can you share your layout code?

Comment: I have shared it .

Comment: It is working fine in my side. Can you post the declaration of selector_leftmenu_exit in colors?

Comment: Why is last **RadioButton** is outside the group? If you want a simple text, you can directly use **TextView**.

Comment: I shared the xml of selector_leftmenu_exit